# ReactJS Api requests

Tags: reactjs, api

I need your help. I'm trying to collect data from themoviedb. I got the link and the key to it. It looks like this:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/76341?api_key=428850e5a5a362ac3ab4dccc1969b0a1
```

When I move here I get json.
I tried to display data on the page. There are no errors, but there is no result. What is the problem and how can the data be displayed here? Here is my code

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

export let GetMovies = () => {

const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/76341?api_key=428850e5a5a362ac3ab4dccc1969b0a1`;
let [movies, setMovies] = useState([])

let fetchData = async () => {
    let response = await fetch(url)
    let data = await response.json()
    setMovies(data);
    console.log(data)
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
},[])

return (<div>
    {movies.length && <h3>{movies.name}</h3>}
        </div>)
}
```

Comment: `movies.length` will never be a truthy value, it will either be 0 when. the data hasn't been fetched yet (due to the default empty array), or it will be `undefined` when your data has been fetched, as `length` isn't a property on your data. PS: Probably not a good idea to share your api key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, the output from the API is json, you need your movies state to store a JSON object, not an array. Also, in your output there is no key as `name` within the main document.

Try these changes:

```
const [movies, setMovies] = useState({});
```

And within JSX do this,

```
{Object.keys(movies).length !== 0 && <h3>{movies.original_title}<h3>}
```

Comment: thanks. I have a question, why i need to use object keys?

Comment: To check whether the movies object is empty or not. When the data will be loaded from the API, it will not be empty, so the heading will display, initially it  is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial variable type and result type saving to state should match.

As you have initialized array but saving object isn't correct type.

Improved:

```
    const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/76341?api_key=428850e5a5a362ac3ab4dccc1969b0a1`;

   export default function GetMovies() {
      let [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
    
      let fetchData = async () => {
        let response = await fetch(url);
        let data = await response.json();
        setMovies(data.genres);
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <div>
          {movies?.length > 0 &&
            movies.map((movie) => <h3 key={movie.id}>{movie.name}</h3>)}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

> You're trying to access field(**name**) which is inside array, Iterate to access.

[Improved Live working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-worker-yyy2u?file=/src/App.js)